# Kartik Select2 load ajax when other input change value

Tags: php, ajax, yii2, jquery-select2, kartik-v

I need to load data with ajax to a Kartik Select2 but only when certain input changes values. Kind of like...

```php
<?= $form->field($model, 'id_list')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
    'data' => [],
    'theme' => Select2::THEME_BOOTSTRAP,
    'options' => [
        'placeholder' => 'List',
    ],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'allowClear' => true,
        'action' => '#input_first'.change // or something
        'ajax' => [
            'url' => Url::to(['/list']),
            'dataType' => 'json',
            'data' => new JsExpression('function(params) { return {q:params.term}; }')
        ],
     ],
 ]);?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to use Select2 with DepDrop plugin (http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/depdrop)?

Comment: Oohh, Exactly what I need. Thanks!